# Parse.com Cloud Code log only returns Input and Result

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to debug some code on parse.com. I am using console.log to print to console various things but when I try to read the log file all I get is the Input and the Result. This is what I have tried so far

```
console.log("whatever") //nothing
console.warn("whatever") //nothing
```

In the terminal

`parse log -l INFO //This gives me just Input and Result`

Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a JSON string, not a regular string. For example: *console.log({"hello":"world!"});*

I can't find the reference, and even they use normal string in their example code, but it works fine with JSON strings.